# Messages must be statically evaluate-able for extraction, on class

Tags: reactjs, react-intl

I need to add formattedMessages, on a method on a React class.

We normally use injectIntl with a HOC and it works, but I am on a React class, and i've tried many things but still get the error:

`Messages must be statically evaluate-able for extraction`

How do i use a formattedMessage in a class?

```
  getDisplayText() {
    const { placeholder, value } = this.props;

    if (!value || value.length === 0) {
      return <div>{placeholder}</div>;
    }

    const messages = defineMessages({
      locations: {
        id: value.length > 1 ? 'SelectInputGrouped.locationsSelected' : 'SelectInputGrouped.oneLocationSelected',
        defaultMessage: '{num} location selected',
        values: { num: value.length },
      },
    });

    return (
      <div>
        <FormattedMessage {...messages.locations} />
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Comment: Did you resolve this issue?

Comment: yes see anser below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way i did it is with i18n itself.. it has support for plurlas: https://www.i18next.com/translation-function/plurals